# How to deploy angular 8 application in local IIS server

Tags: angular

I have created a angular 8 app with multiple sub projects inside it.
and i run the production build command as below.

```
ng build --prod
```

it generated three folders one parent project folder and two folders for two sub projects.
**Kindly let me know how to deploy in local IIS Server.**

Comment: **Try this** complete guide step by step for angular production build deployment on IIS server [angular-6-production-on-iis](https://medium.com/angular-deployment-on-iis/angular-6-production-on-iis-manual-url-refresh-page-error-88f64fb8d5f4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run `ng b --prod --base-href ./` and copy your dist folder into you IIS Project.

The `--base-href` is important then otherwise angular would search for his source files in the root directory of your server.

Als create a `web.config` in your root directory.

Otherwise if you would call url `yourApp / login`, IIS would search for a`login` folder that does not exist. With the config the IIS does not resolve the URL from `yourApp` any more, and angular can do the rest